# Which air traffic controller positions are considered most challenging?

Tags: air-traffic-control

Consider a large ATC facility, where a range of ATC services are provided and each position requires a dedicated person to manage (unlike small airports, where the same guy is ground + tower). Which positions are considered the most demanding, and it would make sense to assign a senior and experienced controller there?

I would imagine, Clearance Delivery is probably the easiest one, then Enroute, Approach / Departure, Ground and finally Tower. What's the training sequence recommended by the authorities for a new controller? After all, assigning a fresh trainee to LAX tower or JFK ground does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: I'm guessing you can find lazy approach control sectors somewhere in the world, just as you can burn yourself out doing clearance delivery at Heathrow in a matter of minutes.

Comment: As worded, this question is essentially asking for opinions. I think you could ask the question without appealing to opinion, though I'm not sure it could be answered objectively. I'm not ready to vote to close, but do think the question needs a rework.

Comment: [Possible dupe](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11748/8730) and [onother possible dupe](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25633/8730)